# ImportError: from django.urls import path is not working

Tags: django

What is the probelm ?I am getting lot of stress with this code.

MY CODE::::

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from basicapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('formpage/',views.form_name_view,name='form_name'),

]
```

PROBLEM///ERROR::::

```
 from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: 1.11.16 is my django verison,

Comment: The answer provided will solve your issue, from version 1.* path was not present in Django yet. It's a new feature from version 2.*

Answer (score 2):

`django.urls.path` is new in Django 2.0. Make sure you use Django 2.0 or if you have to stick to <2.0 use django.conf.urls.url.

Docs for path (2.0): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path

Docs for url (<2.0): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url

It helps to use an editor that manages imports for you like PyCharm or Visual Code or Vi with appropriate plugins or many other.